# Handling Large CSV file using Apache camel

Tags: csv, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have already looked into the earlier post on handling large csv file using camel.
In the below code I have used bindy to handle my CSV file. Also used streaming and tokenizer to further split the file into group of 2000 records.

Still the server gives OOM error when I run this in Production env, work fine in the development machine when processing the same file.

What am I missing?

```
<split streaming="true">
    <tokenize token="\n" group="2000"></tokenize>
        <unmarshal ref="bindyDataformat">
            <bindy type="Csv" classType="com.camel.bindy.input.ABC"/>
        </unmarshal>
        <bean ref="csvBean" method="processAbcCsv"/>
        <marshal ref="bindyDataformat">
             <bindy type="Csv" classType="com.camel.bindy.input.ABC"/>
        </marshal>
        <to uri="{{to.file.processed}}"/>
</split>
```

Comment: How is this route deployed? Do you deploy in Karaf? ServiceMix? I had to tweak my  jvm settings for my run time to handle a 250MB csv file to upload.

Comment: It is deployed as an OSGI bundle, on Jboss 6.0.Karaf console.

Comment: Which run time container?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.4.1.el6_3-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: Sorry missed the JBoss part. You will need to edit the Karaf jvm settings this can be done by editting the karaf config files.

Comment: Can you please provide me with specific file name and path and which params to change